# example of an inhomogenenous markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, matrix-calculus

I have found a very interesting exercice about inhomogeneous markov chains, which I think you are also interested in and hope someone can solve it.

Let $X_{1},X_{2},...$ be a inhomogeneous markov chain with state space $\{0,1\}$ with transition probabilities

$$
\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} = 1 | X_{n} = 0) = \frac{1}{n^{2}}\\
\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} = 0 | X_{n} = 1) = \frac{1}{n^{2}}.
$$

1. $X := \lim_\limits{n \to \infty} X_{n}$ almost surely exists.
2. If $\mathbb{P}(X_{1} = 1) = \mathbb{P}(X_{1} = 0) = \frac{1}{2}$, then $\mathbb{P}(X = 1) = \frac{1}{2}$.
3. If $X_{1} \equiv 1$ then $\mathbb{P}(X = 1) > \frac{1}{2}$.

Im very interested how you would solve it. The solution was discussed in the lecture but I hope that I see a different approach. Maybe with matrix calculation

Comment: That's a great problem. Interesting how narrow the margin is. The approach of showing that the probability of one flip (beyond the certain initial flip) exceeds the probability of two flips by more than $\frac12$ fails ([calculation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi%5E2%2F6+-+1+-+Sum+%5B(pi%5E2%2F6-Sum%5B1%2Fk%5E2,k,1,n%5D)%2Fn%5E2,n,2,5%5D)); if we didn't allow more than two flips we'd actually have $\mathbb P(X=1)\lt\frac12$!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**0. Model:**

The probabilities of a flip from $0$ to $1$ and from $1$ to $0$ coincide hence one can realize the whole sequence $(X_n)$ *pathwisely*, as $$X_n=X_1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}Y_k\pmod2$$ for every $n\geqslant1$, where $(Y_k)$ is independent Bernoulli and, for each $k$, $$P(Y_k=1)=1-P(Y_k=0)=\frac1{k^2}$$
**1. Convergence:**

The series with positive terms $\sum\limits_kE(Y_k)$ converges, hence the random series $\sum\limits_kY_k$ converges almost surely, that is, almost surely, at most finitely many $Y_k$s are not $0$. Thus, the existence of $X=X_1+Y\pmod2$, where $$Y=\sum_{k=1}^\infty Y_k$$

**2. Symmetric case:**

For every $Y$ independent of $X_1$, if $X_1$ is uniform on $\{0,1\}$ then $X_1+Y\pmod2$ is also uniform on $\{0,1\}$. Thus, if $P(X_1=1)=P(X_1=0)=\frac12$ then, indeed, $X$ and every $X_n$ are uniform on $\{0,1\}$, in particular, $P(X=1)=P(X=0)=\frac12$.

**3. Case $X_1=1$ almost surely:**

For every integer valued random variable $S$, $$2P(S\ \text{even})=1+E((-1)^S)$$ hence $$2P(X=1)=1+E((-1)^X)=1+E((-1)^{X_1})\prod_{k=1}^\infty E((-1)^{Y_k})$$ that is, if $P(X_1=1)=1$, $$2P(X=1)=1-\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1-2P(Y_k=1)\right)$$ hence 3. is equivalent to the assertion that $$\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac2{k^2}\right)<0$$ Every term in this product is positive except the $k=1$ term, which is negative, hence, indeed, if $P(X_1=1)=1$ (and even for every $P(X_1=1)>\frac12$), then $$P(X=1)>\frac12$$

Answer (score 2):

So the markov matrices is,
$$
P_n = \begin{pmatrix}
1-\frac{1}{n^2} & \frac{1}{n^2} \\
\frac{1}{n^2} & 1-\frac{1}{n^2}
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}\frac{1}{n^2}
$$ Hence
$$
P_n = I + A\frac{1}{n^2}
$$ Now this means that all matrices $P_n$ can be simultaniously diagonalize. Note that for $v_1 = (1,1)^t$ $Av_1 = 0$ and for $v_2 = (1,-1)^t$ we have
$$
Av_2 = -2 v_2
$$ Hence to find the final probability matrix we need to calculate
$$
\prod_{i=1}^nP_i \to c = \prod_{i=1}^n\left( 1 - \frac{2}{n^2} \right )
$$ Note https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=prod+(1-2%2Fi%5E2)
Then we get probability matrix as
$$
 \prod_{i=1}^nP_i = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&c\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1+c}{2}&\frac{1-c}{2}\\\frac{1-c}{2}&\frac{1+c}{2}\end{pmatrix},
$$ with $c=-0.22$. Now the convergence of the product proves the limit and the evaluation of the matric putting numbers of c in it lead to the answers of 2,3, 3 looks wrong, note that I included the case $n=1$ this case just swaps the states and from this we note that 3 is proven.

Comment: Note that in the partial sum formula that Wolfram|Alpha provides, the quotient of the gamma functions tends to $1$, so we actually have $c=\operatorname{sinc}\left(\sqrt2\pi\right)$. This is related to a more general infinite product formula for the $\operatorname{sinc}$ function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function#Properties).